# 'Future<Badge> Function(BuildContext, ChatsState)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, ChatsState)'

Tags: flutter

When creating a Badge regarding chat notifications, this problem occurred : "The argument type 'Future Function(BuildContext, ChatsState)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, ChatsState)'.". Could someone please help me ?

Below I am uploading my code :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return BlocProvider(
  create: (context) => ChatsBloc(
    // apiClient: context.read<ApiClient>(),
    chatsRepository: context.read<ChatsRepository>(),
    usersRepository: context.read<UsersRepository>(),
  )..add(
      const GetChats(),
    ),
  child: BlocBuilder<ChatsBloc, ChatsState>(
    builder: (context, state) async {
      return Badge(
        showBadge: await context.read<ChatsBloc>().isRead(),
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.mode_comment_outlined,
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

}

This is my Bloc :

```
   Future<bool> isRead() async {
final user = _usersRepository.currentLoginUser;
final isRead = _chatsRepository.findUserUnreadChat(user.id);
return isRead;
```

}

This my repo :

```
   Future<bool> findUserUnreadChat(
   String userId,
   ) async {
   final chatData = await _apiClient.findUserChat(userId);
   if (chatData == null) {
   return false;
   } else {
   final chat = await _fromChatDataToUserChat(chatData);
   return chat.isRead;
   }
  }
```

Thank you very much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `builder` arg of `BlocBuilder` cannot be asynchronous. It needs to return the widget right away.

You should provide the builder function with the result of awaiting `isRead()` through your BLoC messages instead of doing this async work in the build function.

Possibly the `state` element already has that info?